# CMake build error: "More than one file was found with OS independent path 'lib/arm64-v8a/libopencv_java3.so'"

Tags: android, opencv, cmake, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm trying to setup OpenCv 3.4.14 on Android Studio (4.0.0) project which has c++ support from the beginning, (Native project). I'm getting this error over and over again. I searched the web and didn't found any useful solution for that problem, please help.

I followed [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vp20EdU5qjU) for setting up OpenCv on Android Studio. It works well in the video, but for some reason it doesn't work for me.

**Note:**

I've tried to setup OpenCv on projects that don't include c++, and it worked without any problem. What makes me think that the problem here is somewhere in the CMakeLists.txt file.

So i will share here all what i have (after following the video above):

**Project structure:**

[image]

**build.gradle (:app):**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.artest"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags ""
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
            version "3.10.2"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation project(path: ':openCVLibrary3414')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

**build.gradle (:openCVLibrary3414):**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
```

**CMakeLists.txt:**

```
set(pathToProject E:/ArTest)
set(pathToOpenCv C:/OpenCV-android-sdk)

# For more information about using CMake with Android Studio, read the
# documentation: https://d.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html
# Sets the minimum version of CMake required to build the native library.

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE on)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=gnu++11")

include_directories(${pathToOpenCv}/sdk/native/jni/include)

# Creates and names a library, sets it as either STATIC
# or SHARED, and provides the relative paths to its source code.
# You can define multiple libraries, and CMake builds them for you.
# Gradle automatically packages shared libraries with your APK.

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
             native-lib

             # Sets the library as a shared library.
             SHARED

             # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
             native-lib.cpp )

add_library( lib_opencv SHARED IMPORTED)

set_target_properties(lib_opencv PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${pathToProject}/app/src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libopencv_java3.so)

# Searches for a specified prebuilt library and stores the path as a
# variable. Because CMake includes system libraries in the search path by
# default, you only need to specify the name of the public NDK library
# you want to add. CMake verifies that the library exists before
# completing its build.

find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
              log-lib

              # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
              # you want CMake to locate.
              log )

# Specifies libraries CMake should link to your target library. You
# can link multiple libraries, such as libraries you define in this
# build script, prebuilt third-party libraries, or system libraries.

target_link_libraries( native-lib ${log-lib} lib_opencv)
```

**HomeActivity.java:**

```
package com.artest;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Used to load the 'native-lib' library on application startup.
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
        System.loadLibrary("opencv_java3");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Example of a call to a native method
        TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.sample_text);
        tv.setText(stringFromJNI());

        if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
            tv.setText(tv.getText() + ", OpenCv is not working.");
        }
        else {
            tv.setText(tv.getText() + "\n GREAT!!! OpenCv is working.");
            tv.setText(tv.getText() + "\n" + validate(0L, 0L));
        }
    }

    /**
     * A native method that is implemented by the 'native-lib' native library,
     * which is packaged with this application.
     */
    public native String stringFromJNI();

    public native String validate(long matAddrGr, long matAddrRgba);
}
```

**native-lib.cpp:**

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>

extern "C" JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_artest_MainActivity_stringFromJNI(
        JNIEnv* env,
        jobject /* this */)
{
    std::string hello = "Hello from C++";
    return env->NewStringUTF(hello.c_str());
}

extern "C"
jstring Java_com_artest_MainActivity_validate(
        JNIEnv* env,
        jobject, jlong addrGray, jlong addrRgba)
{
    cv::Rect();
    cv::Mat();
    std::string hello = "Hello from validate";
    return env->NewStringUTF(hello.c_str());
}
```

**Error:**

```
More than one file was found with OS independent path 'lib/arm64-v8a/libopencv_java3.so'. If you are using jniLibs and CMake IMPORTED targets, see https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features#automatic_packaging_of_prebuilt_dependencies_used_by_cmake
```

**Build results:**

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > More than one file was found with OS independent path 'lib/arm64-v8a/libopencv_java3.so'. If you are using jniLibs and CMake IMPORTED targets, see https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features#automatic_packaging_of_prebuilt_dependencies_used_by_cmake
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone who struggle configuring OpenCV in a native c++ Android projects, I've found this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sn3YhfY5jqg) useful, it is the best guide for setting up OpenCV on Android. All the work is done only by the CMake file. It worked for me.